# How many and and or can we use in mysql query

Tags: mysql

Im making a search form and no matter what i do my query returning wrong results.

```
$sql = "select * from posts WHERE title like '%$term%' or description like '%$term%' and type='$type' order by id";
```

this is returning results till description but totally ignoring the type. but if i give only the type it works. for example

```
$sql = "select * from posts WHERE type='$type' order by id";
```

can anyone tell me is this happening because the query is too complicated? or am i missing something. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems like you just need some parentheses as `AND` takes precedence over `OR`.

```
$sql = "select * 
from posts 
WHERE (title like '%$term%' or description like '%$term%') and type='$type' order by id";
```

It's also good practice to specify a column list rather than `SELECT *`.